# Why lambda does not change a variable's value

Tags: python, lambda, python-3.5

I have some problem understanding `lambda`. My point is adding `1` to a variable in lambda until some point. 
Example;

```
x = 0
t = lambda y: y+1

while True:
    print ("Hello")
    t(x)
    if x==5: break
```

I thought it will stop after 5 times, but I realized that lambda is adding 1 only once. And this while loop is infinite. Why is that? Why lambda doesn't add 1 to that variable until while loop is finish like `x += 1` ?

Comment: You are not changing the value of x: `x = t(x)`

Comment: @idjaw that's like `global` in functions then, am I right?

Comment: When you do `y+1` you create a new object which is returned by the lambda, but you do not collect the returned value.

Comment: The same way that `y + 1` *alone* won't change `y` *either*.

Comment: I believe that you're confusing about  pass-by-reference vs pass-by-value.

Comment: Imagine it did work the way you imagined, then should `1+y` change the meaning of `1` to become whatever the sum og the current value of `1` added to the value of `y`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to assign the output of `t` to x. What you did now is like doing:

```
def t(y):
    return y+1

x = 0
t(x)
```

Instead of

```
x = t(x)
```

You need to do:

```
x = 0
t = lambda y: y+1

while True:
    print ("Hello")
    x = t(x)
    if x==5: break
```